# How do I STOP Firefox from sorting bookmarks?

Tags: firefox

I have sorted my bookmarks the way I want them. Every time I start a new Firefox session, the bookmarks become alphabetically sorted. How do I turn this OFF (stop automatic sorting)?

Answer (score 0):

Open the Firefox menu and go to

**Library** -> **Bookmarks** -> **Show All Bookmarks**

In the options bar choose **Views** -> **Sort** and select **unsorted**.

This will solve your problem.